# Dutch pre-trained model not working in gensim

Tags: gensim, fasttext

When trying to upload the fasttext model (cc.nl.300.bin) in gensim I get the following error:

```
!wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-crawl/cc.nl.300.bin.gz
!gunzip cc.nl.300.bin.gz
model = FastText_gensim.load_fasttext_format('cc.nl.300.bin')
model.build_vocab(cleaned_text, update=True)

AttributeError: 'FastTextTrainables' object has no attribute 'syn1neg'
```

The code goes wrong when building the vocab with my own dataset. The format of that dataset is all right, as I already used it to build and train other (not pre-trained) Word2Vec and FastText models.

I saw other had the same error on this blog, however their solution did not work for me: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2588

Also, I read somewhere that I should use 'load_facebook_model'? However I was not able to import load_facebook_model at all? Is this even a good way to solve this problem?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using the latest version of Gensim, `4.0.1`, with many improvements to the FastText implementation?

And, there you will definitely want to use `.load_facebook_model()` to load a full `.bin` Facebook-format model:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model

But also note: the post-training expansion of the vocabulary is best considered an advanced & experimental function. It may not offer any improvement on typical tasks - indeed, without careful consideration of tradeoffs & balancing influence of later traiing against earlier, it can make things worse.

A `FastText` model trained on a large, diverse corpus may already be able to synthesize better-than-nothing guess vectors for out-of-vocabulary words, via its subword vectors.

If there's some data with very-different words & word-senses you need to integrate, it will often be better to re-train from scratch, using an equal combination of all desired text influences. Then you'll be doing things in a standard and balanced way, without harder-to-tune and harder-to-evaluate improvised changes to usual practice.

Comment: The simple trick to update gensim did the job.. I thought this was done automatically in Colabs. Thanks for pointing out.

Also thank you for the other suggestions; I still have some questions regarding post-training. You suggest to only use the pre-trained FastText model. Do I understand correctly that you mean by this that I should use model.build_vocab(my_dataset) and should not use model.train(my_dataset)?

Do you have some reading material / papers which I can read that says post-training is more experimental?

Comment: The fact that a FastText model can report vectors, assembled from character n-grams, for words not in its training data means you can use the pre-trained model directly, with absolutely no `.build_vocab()` or `.train()` extra steps. But as noted above, if you have some substantively different words and word-senses in your training-data, the next best thing is to train your own model from scratch.

Comment: The `update=True` method of expanding the vocabulary was a contribution to Gensim a few years ago by a coder who hasn't been around to fix the fact it's often caused crashing problems in `Doc2Vec` models. It wasn't based on any specific published research evaluating its facilities against other options. And, I've not seen any rigorous examples showing how to use it well for good results. So I would turn your question around: did you come across any writeups that make the case for this feature, as being fit for your intended purpose?